# Refresh Token with passport-google-token in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am unable to get **Refresh Token** while using **passport-google-token** package of NodeJS. I am setting **accessType:"offline"** and **prompt:"consent"** with clientID and clientSecret, but refresh_token always returned null or undefined.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');
var GoogleTokenStrategy = require('passport-google-token').Strategy;
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
            clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: config.googleAuth.callbackURL,
            accessType: 'offline',
            prompt: 'consent'
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log("Access Token: " + accessToken);
            console.log("Refresh Token: " + refreshToken); // Always Returned as undefined
            User.upsertGoogleUser(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, function(err, user) {
                return done(err, user);
            });
        }));
};
```